# Two arrays in a function

Tags: python

I would like to create 2 arrays. An array for the name (empty) and a table for points(empty).

My problem is in my condition. I want the points must be inferior to 20.

Here is my code:

```
def demande(nb):
    tabNom = []
    tabCote = []

    for i in range(nb):
        tabNom.append(input("Entrer le " + str(i+1) + " nom svp : "))

        tabCote.append(input("Entrer le " + str(i+1) + " cote svp : "))

        if tabCote > 20:

           print(input("Ressayez svp : "))


    return tabNom, tabCote

nom, cote = demande(3)

print(nom, cote)
```

Do you have an idea ? Please 
Thank you a lot

Comment: do you mean that the values in the arrays should be below 20?

Comment: What do you try to do in your IF?? check if le length of tabCote is less than 20?  ----> if len(tabCote) > 20: ??? Or each item in the list should be smaller than 20?  because you say: "I want the points must be inferior to 20."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def demande(nb):
    tabNom = []
    tabCote = []

    for i in range(nb):
        tabNom.append(input("Entrer le " + str(i+1) + " nom svp : "))

        tabCote.append(input("Entrer le " + str(i+1) + " cote svp : "))

        if int(tabCote[i]) > 20:

           print(input("Ressayez svp : "))


    return tabNom, tabCote

nom, cote = demande(3)
print(nom, cote)
```

try this once

Comment: Normally it's ok now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
def demande(nb):
    tabNom = []
    tabCote = []

    for i in range(nb):
        tabNom.append(input("Entrer le " + str(i+1) + " nom svp : "))

        tabCote.append(input("Entrer le " + str(i+1) + " cote svp : "))

        if tabCote > 20:

           print(input("Ressayez svp : "))


    return tabNom, tabCote
if __name__ == '__main__': # main function

    nom, cote = demande(3)

    print(nom, cote)
```